# In CakePHP, how do I create a form to list models within a date range?

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp

I have a very simple model that includes the auto-filled field much like 'created'. (DateTime format).

I'd like to use the Form helpers if possible, to validate the date fields and whatnot.

I'd like a simple form with a "Begin Date" (YMD, 12 hours), and an "End Date" (same format).

There is already a controller action set up as follows:

```
function view_between($start_date = null, $end_date = null) { 
    // ... stuff that works correctly when the URL is manually entered.
}
```

Have I defined the controller wrong, or how can I pass these values into that function?

The reason I'm stuck is because I tried adding a `$form->input('my_datetime_field' ...)` twice, but obviously the name/id were the same on the respective elements.

I have also tried using `$form->dateTime(...)` with similar results.

I'm not sure how to uniquely identify a Begin and End date selection, when it should interact with a single field.

Am I going about this wrong? A kind shove in the right direction should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify multiple form elements with the same field name, use this syntax:

```
$form->input('Modelname.0.fieldname');
$form->input('Modelname.1.fieldname');
```

Which should return you an array of values to use.

From: http://book.cakephp.org/view/547/Field-naming-convention

Comment: This is way less elegant than I was hoping it would be, but it's what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do an onsubmit that forms a get request that appends start/end dates:

```
echo $form->create('Foos', array('onsubmit'='submitDates(this)'));
```

javascript:

```
function submitDates(frm) {
    // grab dates from inputs, form get string and submit to form.action
    // get should be something like /controller/view_between/YYYY-MM-DD/YYYY-MM-DD
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a FORM, you can only submit it as GET or POST request.
A GET request will attach all form elements to the URL in a format like this:

```
/controller/action?data[Model][field]=value&data[Model][field2]=value
```

That doesn't correspond to Cake URL standards, so you'll have to do some URL rewriting or parsing anyway.

A POST request is just that, the data will end up in `$this->data` in your controller as usual.

Either way, you can't directly feed a form request into a function with parameters. You *could* use Javascript, but I suggest you shouldn't. The best is probably a usual POST request. You just need to rewrite your controller action to get the data from `$this->data`. Name the form fields whatever you want, just make sure you use them correctly in your controller action.